# Unknown factor in bitcoin pool breakdown

Tags: mining-pools, hashpower, money-laundering

Some time ago the breakdown was dangerously close to heaving too heavily towards Deepbit with only a small part unknown/single person miners. Now there's a 34% unknown factor.

What caused this? Are these botnets? People deciding their amortised profit stablises anyway? A drug cartel laundering money?

Comment: Possibly related - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/what-can-be-done-about-the-no-transaction-block-relayer-currently-71-123-170-15

Comment: "close to having to heaving to heavily towards" looks like a typo, but I've no idea what you're trying to say so can't fix it for you

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that we will account for most of the activity, as Bitcoin allows for high anonymity. Some of that hashing power is believed [to come from some botnet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3332/323), but one can't be sure. You could try looking for the owners of the IPs that relay the new blocks and check who they are, but that would be a tedious work that could be easily hidden, for example by relaying blocks through TOR.

Comment: It's an answer but I was looking for some more satisfaction than I could derive myself ;)

Comment: @Lodewijk I wish I could give a more satisfactory answer. Keep the question open for awhile, maybe someone will know more.